# Sum of subspaces $W$ and $W'$ of $V$ equalling $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space and let $W$ and $W'$ be subspaces such that $\dim W \geqslant\frac{3}{4}\dim V, W' \geqslant \frac34\dim V$ and $\dim(W\cap W')\leqslant\frac12\dim V$. Does it hold that $W+W' = V$?

I know that if $U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$, then $\dim(U+W)+\dim(U\cap W) = \dim U +\dim W$.

I have a feeling that this could be applied here, but cannot seem to figure out how?

Answer (score 1):

$$\dim(W+W')=\dim W+\dim W'-\dim(W\cap W')\ge (\frac34+\frac34-\frac12)\dim V=\dim V\,.$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** We always have $\dim(U_1+U_2)\le\dim V$ and $U_1+U_2$ is naturally a subspace of $V$. Compute a lower bound for $\dim(W+W')$ using the formula mentioned. What happens if $\dim U=\dim V$ for a subspace $U\le V$?